# Mysql with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Can anyone help me to clarify that how to connect mysql server with asp.net and all the relevant query command like select,insert etc.
regards
shashi

Answer (score 5):

You need to download the [MySQL Connector .Net](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/), and install it.

Then, instead of using a SqlProvider for your application, you change it to a MySQL Provider, and add a reference to the MySQL.Data assembly that was installed by the connector to your project.  Then add a connection string like usual to your web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnString" 
         connectionString="Server=yy;Database=xx;Uid=zzz;Pwd=abcdefg;" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After that it's pretty much the same.  The provider model means that the MySQL connector provides all the same objects that you're used to, like MySQLConnection, MySQLCommand, etc.

```
MySqlConnection conn;
using(conn=new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)){

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable");

    conn.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    /* process records.... */

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1. You will also need `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` at the top of your source file.